# \usetagform incompatible with microtype?

Tags: mathtools, microtype, patching

It seems that `\usetagform` in `mathtools` package is incompatible with `microtype` package as can be seen in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{mytag}[\textbf]{[}{]}
\usetagform{mytag}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

It raises an error "unable to apply patch 'eqnum'".
What's the problem?

Below is the information of my tex:

- pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
- mathtools.sty    2021/04/12 v1.27 mathematical typesetting tools
- microtype.sty    2021/12/10 v3.0b Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
- using texmaker

Comment: Please tell us which TeX distribution you employ, when you last updated it, and which versions of the `microtype` and `mathtools` packages you use. FWIW, your test document compiles just fine and produces the expected output on my MacTeX2021 system with LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1, microtype 2021/12/10 v3.0b, and mathtools 2021/04/12 v1.27.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for letting me know that! Updated the post.
Seems that the only difference is Texlive vs. MacTex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get rid of this warning (not an error!), load `microtype` with the option `nopatch=eqnum`.

What this patch is supposed to achieve is protrusion of the equation number at the right margin, so that it matches protrusion in normal text (see below). You can manually replicate this patch by adding the relevant commands when defining the new tag form:

```
\newtagform{mytag2}[\textbf]{\leftprotrusion{(}}{\rightprotrusion{)}}
```

Here's a comparison of this minor difference (see how without the patch the `(1)` is slightly shifted to the left):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[nopatch=eqnum]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{mytag}[\textbf]{(}{)}
\newtagform{mytag2}[\textbf]{\leftprotrusion{(}}{\rightprotrusion{)}}
\usetagform{mytag}
\begin{document}
some more text \dotfill (equally inventive)

\begin{equation}
 1+1=2
\end{equation}

some more text \dotfill (equally inventive)

\usetagform{mytag2}
\begin{equation}
 1+1=2
\end{equation}

some more text \dotfill (equally inventive)
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'll check later if there's a possibility of making the patch compatible with `\newtagform`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!!