# Strange interaction of \tagform@ and microtype

Tags: spacing, amsmath, microtype

Consider the following example, in which I'm using `\tagform@` to mimic the look of `\eqref` when trying to add a prime symbol to the equation number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\textcolor{gray}{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq}
    1+2=3
\end{equation}

TEXT \eqref{eq} TEXT

TEXT {\makeatletter\textup{\tagform@{\ref{eq}'}}} TEXT

\eqref{eq} ; TEXT

{\makeatletter\textup{\tagform@{\ref{eq}'}}} ; TEXT

{\textup{(1')}} ; TEXT

\end{document}
```

Without `microtype`, the result is:

[image]

With `microtype`, the result becomes:

[image]

Why would this happen, and is there some way to go back to the normal appearance when using `microtype`?

Comment: microtype patches `\tagform@` to get protrusion right. You could load the package with `nopatch=eqnum`

Comment: @Robert Thank you for this! Since this is a feature rather than a bug, I should probably keep this patch. May I ask what did you mean by "getting protrusion right"? I don't quite understand why is the patched version better than the original one.

Comment: it's for protrusion of the equation tags, see for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628229/7674). Note that within `\eqref` the original meaning is restored, that's why you don't get protrusion in this case (third line in your example, where protrusion is prevented by the indentation), whereas with `\tagform@` only, there will be protrusion (line four).

Comment: @Robert Thank you for the link. Since I have redefined the `\tagform@` in my document class, for the moment perhaps it would be better for me to disable this patch. Later I shall consider defining my tag form in a microtype-compatible way :)

Comment: just so that there's no misunderstanding: the problem is not that you've redefined `\tagform@` (which microtype will patch just fine), but that you're using this command in a context where the original version (ie. "your `\tagform@`" as opposed to "your `\tagform@` patched by microtype") should be used (just like in `\eqref`). You could define something like `\def\myeqref#1{\textup{\@nameuse {MT@patch@saved@\string \tagform@}{#1}}}`